# Яндекс не видит микроразметку

Tags: html, микроразметка

Заметил, что яндекс не видит микроразметку. В гугле нормально снипеты отображаются. Что это может быть и как исправить? Сайт https://travel-kassa.ru

Comment: Проверьте в Яндекс Вебмастере, там и узнаете какие ошибки есть

Comment: Что значит "не видит"? Какие именно сниппеты вы ожидаете, есть ли пример на том же яндексе (или в его справке)?